# How to incorporate a fellowship into a CV

Tags: cv

I am updating my CV for graduate school applications and I have an awards/honors section and I am unsure how to incorporate a fellowship I received. With the way I have things formatted, every entry looks something like:

> *Name of award*               *Date when I received award and institution name if relevant*
>
> Description of the award

In every other instance, the description doesn't refer back to me in any way but I am having a hard time doing this with this fellowship. The best that I have been able to come up with is along the lines of

> *Summer Research Fellowship*               *Summer 2016, Blah Blah Blah University*
>
> I was one of four graduate students from Blah Blah Blah University's Mathematics Department to receive a fellowship during the Summer of 2016. I worked under Dr. Something, researching stuff that contributed towards my thesis.

Does this seem alright? Also, the research I did this summer is a part of my thesis, however my thesis is not complete yet and will not be until the spring. The way its written now makes it seem like my thesis is written (at least to me), so is there a better way to state this and make it seem more ongoing?

Answer (score 1):

You're generally spot on, but I would tailor this a little more for the benefit of assessors. In evaluating fellowships, I would like to know the following:

1. Was it a competitive grant?
2. How long was the award?
3. How much was the award?
4. What was the research topic?
5. What were the outputs?

Modifying your example above:

> Summer Research Fellowship: December 2016-February 2017
>   Macquarie University
>
> The Fellowship is a competitive grant awarded to undergraduate students in the Department of Mathematics. The grant consisted of direct research costs and living expenses worth $20,000. Under the supervision of Professor Geoffrey Killington I worked on a drug trial for patients with metastatic melanoma. The work I did resulted in two conference papers and a manuscript (currently in press).

Good luck!